# Traditional alternatives to Caputure Words Sequence information in NLP

Tags: nlp, feature-engineering

What were the traditional/earlier methods in which NLP researchers captured the word sequence information through feature engineering?

I know the current methods which rely on deep learning models like roBERT and BERT and work well with capturing sequence information. I also know about embeddings like word2vec, but they fail to capture the sequence information.

For example, I would like a feature which can differentiate between
`"cat ran after the dog."` and `"dog ran after the cat."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different methods, it depends what kind of sequential task.

- [Conditional Random Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) are typically used for [sequence labeling tasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling) like [POS tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) or [NER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition).
- [n-gram models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#n-gram_models) can be used for standard language models, but n-grams can also be used as features in various tasks where order matters. However the larger $n$ the more data is required, so it's rare to go beyond $n=5$ and this is a limitation for tasks which require long distance relations to be represented.
- In order to reasonably capture semantics, the traditional approach is to deploy a chain of components: [POS tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging), syntactic parsing (e.g. [dependency parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar)), then [semantic role labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_role_labeling). This would result in an explicit semantic representation of the sentence.